# Erroneous "undefined symbol" warnings in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: workbench

Although I'm very much fond of Worlfram Workbench's ability
to recognize unused or undefined symbols, sometimes it 
really annoys me.

What I mean is that in some constructions, that are syntactically 
perfectly valid but probably too complicated for WWB's parser, I
get erroneous "undefined symbol" warnings.

Here is one of the examples. It is not a working code, just some
piece of my work that I extracted from an existing project and
renamed the functions just to demonstrate the problem.

[image]

<s>To my knowledge, the iteration variable of the `For` loop is already
shielded, so there is no reason to add it to the `Block`'s list of local variables, as WWB probably would like me to.</s> My bad, thanks to Kuba for the explanation.

Then there is the thing with replacements. The rule `fun1[-fun2[q1,d1_:4], m_]:>fun1[fun2[q1,d1], m]` is perfectly fine, but for some reason WWB complains about `q1` and `d1` being undefined, that doesn't make any sense to me.

I wonder if there are known workaround for this kind of annoyances? I 
don't want to switch to another IDE or disable all "undefined symbol", 
warnings since in most cases they are really useful.

Here is the code of the example

```
Foobar::usage =
"";


(* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *)

Begin["Foobar`Private`"]
fun1::usage="";
fun2::usage="";
fun3::usage="";
fun4::usage="";

fds2LoopsSE[expr_,q1_,q2_,p_]:=
    (fun4[FixedPoint[fun3[#,q1,q2,p]&,expr,5]]/. {
        fun1[-fun2[q1,d1_:4], m_]:>fun1[fun2[q1,d1], m],
        fun1[-fun2[q2,d1_:4], m_]:>fun1[fun2[q2,d1], m],
        fun1[fun2[p, d11_:4]-fun2[q1, d12_:4], m_]:>fun1[fun2[q1, d12]-fun2[p, d11],m],
        fun1[fun2[p, d11_:4]-fun2[q2, d12_:4], m_]:>fun1[fun2[q2, d12]-fun2[p, d11],m],
        fun1[fun2[q2, d11_:4]-fun2[q1, d12_:4], m_]:>fun1[fun2[q1, d12]-fun2[q2, d11],m]
    })/;!FreeQ[expr,q1] && !FreeQ[expr,q2];

Foobar[ex_Integer]:=
    Block[{res=ex},

        For[iv = 1,iv<=10,iv++,
            res = res + iv;
        ];

        res = res /. DDD[AAA[{a_,b_}]] :> CCC[BBB[{a,b}]];      

        res
    ];

End[]
```

Comment: `For` is not a scoping construct. `i = 0; For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, {}]; i`

Comment: My bad, I corrected the original post. Comes from the fact that I never use `For` myself, but have to work with legacy code that contains lots of such loops. However, the replacement rules are correct, right? Or is there something else that I overlooked?